# Connecting to Azure IoT hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am developing some sample IoT application using visual studio, I need to provide connectionstring can some one help me where I can get connectionstring details.

connectionString = "HostName= ;DeviceId=;SharedAccessKey=?;

For SharedAccessKey I have given Device Key, But its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your Azure Dashboard, open the IoT Hub blade, and look at the top for **Devices** (followed by Settings and Delete).  This will bring up the Device Explorer blade, click on any device to get the connection information.

Alternately use the Device Explorer Windows application.  From the Management tab, right-click on a device for a context menu that includes copy connection string.

For info on the Device Explorer application see...
[GitHub How to use Device Explorer for IoT Hub devices](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/tools/DeviceExplorer/doc/how_to_use_device_explorer.md)

Look about 1/3 page down for

> Download a pre-built version of the Device Explorer application

Answer (score 0):

For connecting to IOT hub from client application you can use the following command.

DeviceClient.Create(iotHubUri, new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey("myDevice", deviceKey));